# Rest client design decisions

Tags: java, android, design-patterns, retrofit

I'm developing a rest client using retrofit. The rest server is using oauth as authentication. For this task I don't have to care about the token expiring. So basically I first make a request for the token and then append that to all subsequent calls.
As of now I'm using two classes. One to get the access token and another one for everything else. I think I would like to merge these two... but I'm not sure how to do that.

The first class only has one method which takes a username and password and a retrofit callback interface. I like the simplicity of the callback but would like to somehow abstract it so I could easily change from retrofit to something else if needed.

```
public class RequestAccessToken implements IRequestAccessToken {
    private String username;
    private String password;

    private IRestAPI client;


    public RequestAccessToken()
    {
        RestAdapter restAdapter = new RestAdapter.Builder()
                .setEndpoint(Config.ENDPOINT)
                .build();
        client = restAdapter.create(IRestAPI.class);
    }

    @Override
    public void requestAccessToken(String username, String password, Callback callback) {
        String grantType = Config.grantType;
        String clientId = Config.clientId;
        String clientSecret = Config.clientSecret;

        client.getAccessToken(grantType, username, password, clientId, clientSecret, callback);
    }
}
```

The second class takes the access token as constructor argument and appends it to all http requests.

```
public class RestClient implements IRestClient {
    private static final String TAG = RestClient.class.getSimpleName();
    private IRestAPI client;

    public RestClient(final String accessToken)
    {
        RequestInterceptor requestInterceptor = new RequestInterceptor()
        {
            @Override
            public void intercept(RequestFacade request) {
                request.addHeader("Authorization", "Bearer " + accessToken);
            }
        };

        RestAdapter restAdapter = new RestAdapter.Builder()
                .setEndpoint(Config.ENDPOINT)
                .setRequestInterceptor(requestInterceptor)
                .build();
        client = restAdapter.create(IRestAPI.class);
    }

    @Override
    public List<User> requestUsers() {
        return client.requestUsers();
    }

    @Override
    public List<Soemthing> requestSomething() {
        return client.requestSomething();
    }

    @Override
    public List<SoemthingElse> requestSomethingElse() {
        return client.requestSomethingElse();
    }
}
```

I would love some input and suggestions on how to do this better and perhaps merge the two classes. I'm thinking of making the requestAccessToken method of the RequestAccessToken a static member of the RestClient class. At least that would merge the two class. But I'm using a factory to create the RestClient and if I declare a static method on it which I use throughout my code I get tight coupling... Suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After discussing this elsewhere I came up with the following code.

```
public class RestClient implements IRestClient {
    private static final String TAG = RestClient.class.getSimpleName();
    private IRestAPI client;
    private String username;
    private String password;
    private RequestAccessToken requestAccessToken;
    private Access access;

    private static RestClient singleton;

    // TODO: use Dagger
    public static RestClient getInstance()
    {
        if(singleton == null)
        {
            singleton = new RestClient();
        }
        return singleton;
    }

    /**
     * Access declared as private to prevent instantiation outside of this class.
     */
    private RestClient()
    {
        requestAccessToken = new RequestAccessToken();
    }

    /**
     * Request an access token.
     *
     * @return A string containing the access token
     */
    public String requestAccessToken(String username, String password)
    {
        this.username = username;
        this.password = password;
        this.access = requestAccessToken.requestAccessToken(username, password);
        return this.access.getAccess_token();
    }

    /**
     * Wrapper for {@link #requestAccessToken(String, String) requestAccessToken}
     * @return
     */
    public String requestAccessToken()
    {
        if(username == null || password == null) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("missing user/pass");
        }
        return requestAccessToken(username, password);
    }

    /**
     * Eventually we want to look at Access.getExpires_in() and return weather or not the token is
     * expired.
     *
     * @return value indicating weather or not the token is expired.
     */
    public boolean isAccessTokenExpired()
    {
        return false;
    }

    /**
     * Return an instance of a rest client with a valid access token.
     * @return
     */
    private IRestAPI getClient()
    {
        if(access == null)
        {
            requestAccessToken();
        }
        if(isAccessTokenExpired())
        {
            // Refresh token
        }
        if(client == null) {
            RequestInterceptor requestInterceptor = new RequestInterceptor() {
                @Override
                public void intercept(RequestFacade request) {
                    request.addHeader("Authorization", "Bearer " + access.getAccess_token());
                }
            };

            RestAdapter restAdapter = new RestAdapter.Builder()
                    .setEndpoint(Config.ENDPOINT)
                    .setLogLevel(RestAdapter.LogLevel.FULL)
                    .setRequestInterceptor(requestInterceptor)
                    .build();
            client = restAdapter.create(IRestAPI.class);
        }
        return client;
    }

    /**
     * Login to the api and get a access token.
     *
     * @param username
     * @param password
     */
    @Override
    public void login(String username, String password)
    {
        Log.d(TAG, "login");
        requestAccessToken(username, password);
    }

    /**
     * Request a list of organizations.
     * @return List of Organizations.
     */
    @Override
    public List<Organization> requestOrganizations() {
        Log.d(TAG, "requestOrganizations");
        // TODO: error handling
        // TODO: caching... which isn't http
        return getClient().requestOrganizations();
    }

    // Add more api requests here

}
```

Comment: Naturally it's not enough to look at the expiration date of the access token. The class should handle the error message returned from the server in case the token is expired... but it doesn't.